# Cannot access MySQL database from my website, but can access via browser?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to hook up my website to my MySQL database on my new webhost, and I'm running into a few issues I can't resolve.

If I navigate to `mywebsite.com/phpmyadmin/`, I'm presented with an HTTP authorization, and upon successful entry of that, my PHPMyAdmin login page, where I can log-in as my user and see my databases. Yet, if I try to connect via PHP through my website, I receive the error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'mywebsite.com/phpmyadmin' (11)
```

My connection info is:

```
$this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=mywebsite.com/phpmyadmin;dbname=mydb;charset=utf8','me','myPassword');
```

I'm running LAMP on Ubuntu 14. Is there any particular reason this is failing?

Comment: is it some hosting company? they must have some FAQ hot to connect directly to MySQL server and usually external connections are forbidden for mysql for security reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHPMyAdmin is a database **client application**, not a database server.

You need to provide connection information to your database server (which will probably be `localhost`)

Comment: How do I find what my database server connection info should be? You say "probably" localhost...

Comment: Consult the documentation for your hosting service.

Comment: Trust me, I've tried. I can't find anything relating to DigitalOcean for this problem.

Comment: Then guess that its localhost and see what happens.

Comment: Alright, so it's working now with 'localhost'. Why is my connection info 'localhost' when my website is on their servers? Is there anyway I can point it to a different hostname, if I wanted to?

Comment: Your host would have to set that up for you. Unless you need remote access, there's no reason to change it.

Comment: Because their server is running the HTTP server **and** the MySQL server. You can point it to whatever hostname you like providing that said host is listening for a database client and that the host is not firewalling the outgoing connection. It's generally a bad idea to do database connections over the Internet, running a webserver (with SSL) is usually a better bet).

Comment: Hmm, okay. I can deal with that. My previous website host had me point my connection host info towards `mysql.mywebsite.com`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect to the mysql server rather than the phpMyAdmin interface (won't work).
In this case it's you will use localhost (Really). Why? because localhost just points to the server's local IP. You can also point it to any hostname which points to the server's IP so it knows which server to connect to! :)

Comment: Localhost, in this case, does not point to the server's local IP. It is special cased and the connection will be handled using UNIX sockets instead of TCP/IP.